# mobilefirst-cli ERR! Error: ry.npmjs.org/cordova-plugin-compat

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am using the MFP 7.1 with cordova project (mfp cordova).

I am able to add the iOS environment successfully (mfp cordova platform add iOS), but I got error when I try to add Android environment.

Following the exception:
mobilefirst-cli ERR! Error: ry.npmjs.org/cordova-plugin-compat
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-plugin-compat

```
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/cordovacmd/lib/cordova-cli.js:251:41)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:117:20)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:979:11)
at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

Comment: can you provide reproductions steps? did you create a new cordova app with mfp and get this error when trying to add the android platform?

Comment: Can you please provide the entire error log? How did you install mfp cordova?

Comment: The project has been creating using the "mfp cordova create myApp" and using the ionic template from this site: https://github.com/csantanapr/mfp-ionic-templates

I have created the iOS environment few days ago and it is working fine. Today, I tried to create the Android environment (mfp cordova platform add android) and I received the error described in the post

Answer (score 0):

I cannot confirm this...
Using 7.1.0.00.20160401-2108 I've tried the following: `mfp cordova create`

I then provided the name and version for the app, and selected the two supported platforms: iOS and Android. The app was then created, with both platforms.

I would try to perhaps update your npm installation.